# what is the maximum size of CLOB in SAP hana in bytes?

Tags: hana, clob

> I have a table in SAP hana, which has a column of type CLOB, i want
>   to know how many bytes can a column of type CLOB can store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SAP HANA Developer Guide and [SAP Help](http://help-legacy.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a1569875191014b507cf392724b7eb/content.htm#loio20a1569875191014b507cf392724b7eb___csql_data_types_1sql_data_types_introduction_lob), the maximum size for LOB (Large Object Types) including BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB and TEXT is 2 GB.

Comment: Is 2 gb default size?

Comment: No, the internal storage for LOB columns is dynamically sized. Depending on the size of your payload data, the internal storage will use more or less memory.